# Is there a listener for when ImageView renders its image?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view

I want to measure the performance of my image loading, and so I'd like to know exactly when the image bitmap has finally been rendered on screen. Is there a listener for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using profiler for this: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: That tool looks good, but I'd like to do this in code ideally.